# How to store tables using jquery ajax django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I have written a model named tablestoreajax. It contains name and age fields. I want to store this table field values using ajax but without using json. Am new to django.
models.py

```
class tablestoreajax(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

tablestore.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1').on('submit',function(){
        var name=$('#id1').val()
        var age=$('#id2').val()
         var dataString = {name:name,age:age};
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        data:dataString,
        url:'/ajaxdisplay/',
        success:function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
  });
    });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
name<input type="text" id="id1" name="name1">
age<input type="text" id="id2" name="age1">
<input type ="submit" id="sub" value="save">
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to write my views with get method. How to proceed? I need your help

Answer (score 1):

Simply define a url and view just as you would regularly.

## Urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('myproject.app.views',
    url(r'^ajaxdisplay/$', 'ajaxView'),
)
```

## Views

```
def ajaxView(request):
    #...
```

If you want, you can use json to return variables you may want to return to your client.

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def ajaxView(request):
    data = {
           'name':request.GET['name'],
            'age':request.GET['age'],
           }
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

## Client

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    data:dataString,
    url:'/ajaxdisplay/',
    datatype:'json',         //don't forget to specify datatype
    success:function(data) {
        alert(data.name);
        alert(data.age);
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't have to use json.  What type of data do you need to return?